# Apple Font Tools cannot install on Catalina

Tags: macos, catalina, font

I am trying to install the [Apple Font Tools](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=font) to be able to use the command line to edit font ascender via command line:

`ftxdumperfuser -t hhea -A f Tajawal-Medium.ttf.ttf`

1. **I tried to download Font Tools for xcode 11 and install it.** but command is not working. I get `Command not found
2. **Then I tried to download `OS X Font Tools` and install it,**
       following this guide: [install-apple-font-tools.sh](https://gist.github.com/thetrevorharmon/9afdeb41a74f8f32b9561eeb83b10eff)

Now when I run the command I get:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: __ZN11FTExceptionD1Ev
Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/ftxdumperfuser
Expected in: /Library/Frameworks/FontToolbox.framework/Versions/A/FontToolbox
in /usr/local/bin/ftxdumperfuser
```

How can I fix this? and run the font tools on macOS Catalina? Or any alternative way to be able to fix font vertical alignment, with ascender and lineGap?

Comment: looks like brew installed ftxdumperfuser & it is being used where Xcode's tool should be used. Run `brew unlink ftxdumperfuser` & retry. If it doesn't work, link it again using `brew link ftxdumperfuser` & wait for an answer (:

Comment: when I run unlink I get: `Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/ftxdumperfuser`

Comment: oh sorry then ..